# Where to store key-value pairs for runtime retrieval from within Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

In a Cloud Function I need to retrieve a bunch of key-value pairs to process. Right now I'm storing them as json-file in Cloud Storage.

Is there any better way?

Env-variables don't suite as (a) there are too many kv pairs, (b) the same gcf may need different sets of kv depending on the incoming params, (c) those kv could be changed over time.

BigQuery seems to be an overkill, also given that some kv have few levels of nesting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/), but it's not persistent see the [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview).

> Cloud Memorystore for Redis provides a fully managed in-memory data
>   store service built on scalable, secure, and highly available
>   infrastructure managed by Google. Use Cloud Memorystore to build
>   application caches that provides sub-millisecond data access. Cloud
>   Memorystore is compatible with the Redis protocol, allowing easy
>   migration with zero code changes.

[Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/connecting-vpc) enables you to connect from the Cloud Functions environment directly to your Memorystore instances.

Note: Some resources, such as Memorystore instances, require connections to come from the same region as the resource.

**Update**

For persisted storage you could use Firestore.

See a tutorial about using [Use Cloud Firestore with Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-firestore)

Comment: Thanks! I stumbled upon Memorystore, but I thought it's more a way to cache/store data for stateless functions, rather than persistent way to store key-value formatted configs.

Comment: @syldman I will correct than the answer. Memorystore is not persistent. I was reading from you that you have a mechanism to popule the key-value if it's empty.

Comment: So my suspicion was right. 
Thanks for pointing at Firestore! I haven't yet looked at it.